# Finding minimum temperature for a month in a data set

Tags: matlab, for-loop

I have already made a function which extracts all temeperatures from a data set for a certain time for a given month and year.

Which looks like `exctractperiod(data, year, month, time)`

I now want to find a minimum temperature for a certain month, say January, across many years. For example if I look at the month January between the year 1997 and 2006.  Now I want the lowest registered temperatue for January between 1997-2006.

My progress so far (keep in mind this is just a rough idea for what I want)

```
for i = 1:12
  for z = 1:x+1

    year=startyear:1:endyear;
    year(z)

   p = extractperiodtwo(DATA, year, month, time);    

end
```

I want to know how I can write my `for` loops so that for, say `month 1`, it goes through the years 1997-2006 and finds the lowest temperatue. Then for the next loop it goes through the years 1997-2006 for `month 2`. This should then repeat until month 12.

The variable `p` stores all the temperatures for year YYYY month MM.

Don't take my program all to seriously it was just a rough write-up to give myself a idea for how it should look. Maybe it clarifies my question.

Answer (score 0):

You're probably looking for something like this:

```
mintemp = inf(1,12); % initialize to infinity for each month
for month = 1:12
  for year = 1997:2006
    p = extractperiodtwo(DATA, year, month, time);
    temp = min(p); % assuming `p` contains multiple temperatures?
    mintemp(month) = min(mintemp(month), temp); % update current month's min temp
  end
end
```

Comment: Why is the  `mintemp =  inf(1,12);` necessary? Regarding the loops you wrote. So if I look at this from the perspective of a flowchart how will this execute?  Will this begin by taking the months 1:12 for year 1997 and for the next loop it will take the months 1:12 for the year 1998 and so on? How would this proceed?

Comment: @JonnyCola: Copy-paste this into the MATLAB editor and step through it using the debugger. You'll learn a lot more than I can explain. The first `for` loop assigns `month=1`, then the next line assigns `year=1997`, then those values are used to obtain `p`. When execution reaches the first `end`, it goes back to the corresponding for, and assigns `year=1998`, then gets the next `p`. Etc. So for each month, it goes through all years.

Comment: The initialization if `mintemp` is necesary because otherwise `mintemp(month) = min(mintemp(month), temp)` will be meaningless: you're using the existing value there, so you need to give it a value first.